# Custom module is not showing up for regular user

Tags: 6

This is what Drupal returns if URL defined from the module is accessed:

> Access denied
>   You are not authorized to access this page.

THe permissions are all checked for authorized, and anonymous users.

The implementation of `hook_menu()` is the following.

```
function qarena_menu() {
  $items = array();

  // This determines the path used to show the form and also makes a menu entry
  // This first path is for the entry form
  $items['qarena'] = array(
    'title' => t('QArena'),
    'page callback' => 'qarena_display_page',
    // drupal_get_form, registers the given form in drupal.
    'access arguments' => array('ask question'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: show your module code if you can

Comment: which parts, would be necessary?

Comment: Check hook_menu implementation of the URL you are accessing in custom module.. Update the Question with the hook_menu code !

Comment: Can you confirm  do you see permission named 'ask question' in permissions matrix setting page ?? which version of Drupal are you using ?

Comment: yep, everything is ticked up, it's drupal6

Comment: Clear menu cache and make sure "ask question" permission is given to the user who is logged in...

Comment: I really have no idea how would I do that :(

Comment: Try with `'access arguments' => array('access content'), `

Answer (score 3):

[user_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7), the access handler used by default from Drupal when no other access handler has been set, returns `TRUE` (the user has access to the menu) only when the permission string is one defined from a module, and the user has that permission.

If "ask question" is not a permission defined from any module with [hook_permission()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) (Drupal 7 or higher), or [hook_perm()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_perm/6) (Drupal 6 or lower), then you will get an access denied error.

Once you are sure a module (including the one you are developing) defines the permission you want to use, be sure the same permission is assigned to any of the roles the currently logged-in user has. For example, if the user has the role of *editor*, then the permission you are using needs to be assigned to the *editor* role, or to the *authenticated user* role.